# How do I set up token authentication properly with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using DRF 1.10 and Python 3.5.

I am trying to use DRF's `rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token` to authenticate a user on login. This is what I have:

`views.py`

```
class LoginView(views.APIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.get(username=serializer.data['username'])
            token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

            response = {}
            response['user'] = serializer.data
            response['token'] = token.key

            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        username = attrs.get("username").lower()
        password = attrs.get("password")

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            attrs["user"] = user
            return attrs
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Unable to login with credentials provided."
            )
```

On login I want to provide the user with a token and on log out I want to delete that token. The problem is that when I attempt to delete the token by finding the token with the token's key and the user that it is related to, I am unable to find the token. The logout view is here:

```
class LogoutView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(" ")[1]
            invalidate_token = Token.objects.filter(key=token, user=request.user)
            invalidate_token.delete()

        return Response({ detail: "Logged out"}, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
    except:
        return Response({"error": ["Token does not exist!"]}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I ran into problems when I tried to log a user out. I realized that `request.user` was still an `AnonymousUser` and not a `User`. How do I go about fixing this?

[image: Header from Postman]

This is my header in postman.

Comment: If you have Django Admin installed, you can view your Auth Tokens in there. Compare them to make sure the token you're using still exists and is associated with the correct django user.

Comment: @Soviut Just viewed the Admin tool. The tokens do exist and are associated with the correct user but still does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Because Token is stateless it is not same with standart Django session authentification, you should put that token in all requests.
For testing purposes you can install some chrome plugin for modify authorization headers, for example [modheader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en-US)
Put it in header:

```
Authorization: Token <your_toke_string>
```

And user will be authenticated

Comment: I use postman to make the login/logout requests. The token is in the header. I made sure that it was correct. The problem is not the token missing because in my logout view, `token` is correct. The problem is `Token.objects.filter(key=token, user=request.user)` and in particular, `request.user`. That is not returning the `User` object as it should be.

Comment: @A.Wong so I gues your token is incorect, because `request.user` should return User object, and `request.auth` should return  `BasicToken` instance. What is your `request.auth` value now when headers is set?

Comment: It is set to `None`.

Comment: @A.Wong so this means that your authorization headers incorect. Try to use chrome app which I link in answer or check your headers format in the postman.

Comment: I have included my header from postman in the post above. I also checked with your app. Things all look correct.

Comment: @A.Wong well I don't know, you can check that login value by `Token` query of your user. Is it will the same in `Token.objects.get(user=your_user)` with token in headers, maybe that toke n value does not exists, and you need to create new one

Comment: When I run `Token.objects.get(user=user)` in the login view, it returns the same token I use to try to log the user out with. Also, in the logout view, if I ran `Token.objects.get(key=token_key)` instead of `Token.objects.get(key=token_key, user=user)` I get the correct token. I know this because when I call `token.user`, it returns the correct user. The problem must be that for some reason, `TokenAuthorization` is not giving me a `request.user`.